# Color Property On Custom Attribute

Tags: vb.net

i wrote a custom attribute and got the following Color property that I want the user to be able to indicate the color property in the attribute on a class:

```
    Private _ColumnColor As System.Drawing.Color
    Public Property ColumnColor() As System.Drawing.Color
        Get
            Return _ColumnColor
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As System.Drawing.Color)
            _ColumnColor = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
"Property or field 'ColumnColor' does not have a valid attribute type
```

How can I resolve?

Thanks

Comment: Does your project reference System.Drawing"?

Answer (score 0):

I would start with adding the [AttributeUsage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributetargets.aspx) to your property

```
<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)> _
Private _ColumnColor As System.Drawing.Color
    Public Property ColumnColor() As System.Drawing.Color
        Get
            Return _ColumnColor
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As System.Drawing.Color)
            _ColumnColor = value
        End Set
    End Property
```